# How could I add a link for the "Edit" icon to private Bitbucket repo?

Tags: r, bitbucket, bookdown

[image]
Hello, related to Bookdown I am editing the "index.Rmd" and "_output.yaml" file in order to make functional the "Edit" button.
I followed the instructions detailed in this page: 29.4 Edits and source code

But when render my book and I click on that "Edit icon" I get again the error page in Bitbucket.
error404_bitbucket

I have a private bitbucket and I added the following lines of code in the :
"_output.yml"

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  css: style.css
  config:
    toc:
      collapse: section
      before: |
        <li><a href="./">Demo Book</a></li>
      after: |
        <li><a href="https://bitbucket.whatever.com/projects/my_repo_name/my_bookdown" target="blank">Published with bookdown</a></li>
    edit:
      link: bitbucket.whatever.com/my_username/my_repo_name/edit/master/%s
      text: "Suggest an edit"

    download: ["pdf", "epub"]
```

"index.Rmd"

```
title: "bookdown"
author:"authors"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
documentclass: book
bibliography:
- book.bib
- packages.bib
description: 
  Thats it
link-citations: yes
always_allow_html: yes
github-repo: my_bitb_username/my_repo_name
```

[image]
Does anybody know if Bookdown can have a Edit button that , when you click on, it will redirect you to the Rdm file to edit (if you have permissions to edit) ?
Many thanks!

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/1435